# Shorter notation for matching hypotheses in Coq?

Tags: coq, theorem-proving, coq-tactic

I find myself often wanting to refer to hypotheses by their type rather than by their name; especially in proofs with inversions on semantic rules, i.e., rules with several cases each of which may have multiple antecedents.

I know how to do this with `match goal with ...`, as in the following trivial example.

```coq
Lemma l0:
  forall P1 P2,
    P1 \/ (P1 = P2) ->
    P2 ->
    P1.
Proof.
  intros.
  match goal with H:_ \/ _ |- _ => destruct H as [H1|H2] end.
  assumption.
  match goal with H: _ = _ |- _ => rewrite H end.
  assumption.
Qed.
```

*Is there a more concise way? Or a better approach?*

(Introduction patterns, like `intros [???? HA HB|??? HA|????? HA HB HC HD]`, are not an option—I am tired of finding the right number of `?`s!)

For instance, is it possible to write a `grab` tactic to combine a pattern and a tactic, as in

```coq
  grab [H:P1 \/ _] => rename H into HH.
  grab [H:P1 \/ _] => destruct H into [H1|H2].

  grab [P1 \/ _] => rename it into HH.
  grab [P1 \/ _] => destruct it into [H1|H2].
```

From my understanding of [Tactic Notations](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/user-extensions/syntax-extensions.html#tactic-notations), it is not possible to have a *cpattern* as an argument, but maybe there is another way?

Ideally, I would like to be able to use an hypothesis pattern instead of an identifier in any tactic as in Isabelle:

```coq
rename ⟨P1 \/ _⟩ into HH.
destruct ⟨P1 \/ _⟩ as [H1|H2].
rewrite ⟨P1 = _⟩.
```

But I imagine this to be quite an invasive change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate over all the assumptions until you find a matching one:

```
Tactic Notation "summon" uconstr(ty) "as" ident(id) :=
  match goal with H : _ |- _ => pose (id := H : ty) end.
```

The trick is that you take the type to be found not as a pattern, but, well, as a type :). Specifically, if you issue something like `summon (P _) as id`, then Coq will take the `_` as an unsolved existential variable. In turn, each assumption will be typechecked against `P _`, trying to instantiate that hole along the way. When one succeeds, the `pose` names it `id`. The iteration arises because `match goal` will keep retrying with different matches until something sticks or everything fails.

You can define a form without `as` that just names the found thing `it` (while kicking anything else out):

```
Tactic Notation "summon" uconstr(ty) :=
  let new_it := fresh "it"
   in try (rename it into new_it); summon ty as it.
```

Ta-da!

```
Lemma l0 : forall P1 P2, P1 \/ (P1 = P2) -> P2 -> P1.
Proof.
  intros.
  summon (_ \/ _).
  destruct it.
  assumption.
  summon (_ = _).
  rewrite it.
  assumption.
Qed.
```

You can also get your `=>` syntax. I don't think it's terribly useful, but...

```
(* assumption of type ty is summoned into id for the duration of tac
   anything that used to be called id is saved and restored afterwards,
   if possible. *)
Tactic Notation "summon" uconstr(ty) "as" ident(id) "=>" tactic(tac) :=
  let saved_id := fresh id
   in try (rename id into saved_id);
      summon ty as id; tac;
      try (rename saved_id into id).

Lemma l0 : forall P1 P2, P1 \/ (P1 = P2) -> P2 -> P1.
Proof.
  intros.
  summon (_ \/ _) as H => destruct H.
  assumption.
  summon (_ = _) as H => rewrite H.
  assumption.
Qed.
```

## Old answer

(You may want to read this, because the above solution is really a variant of this one, and there's more explanation here.)

You can summon an assumption matching a type pattern into a name with `eassert (name : ty) by eassumption.`.

```
Lemma l0 : forall P1 P2, P1 \/ (P1 = P2) -> P2 -> P1.
Proof.
  intros.
  eassert (HH : _ \/ _) by eassumption.
  destruct HH.
  assumption.
  eassert (HH : _ = _) by eassumption.
  rewrite HH.
  assumption.
Qed.
```

Why is this an improvement? Because the `_ \/ _` and `_ = _` are now full types, not just patterns. They just contain unsolved existential variables. Between `eassert` and `eassumption`, these variables get solved at the same time the matching assumption is located. Tactic notations can definitely work with types (i.e. terms). Sadly, there appears to be a bit of a mishap in the parsing rules. Specifically, the tactic notation needs an untyped term (so we don't try and fail to resolve the variables too early), so we need `uconstr`, but [there's no `luconstr`](https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/arc/coq-club/2015-10/msg00054.html), meaning we're forced to add extraneous parentheses. To avoid bracket-mania, I've reworked the syntax of your `grab`. I'm also not entirely sure if your `=>` syntax makes much sense, because why not just bring the name into scope for good, instead of only on the `=>`, as you seem to imply?

```
Tactic Notation "summon" uconstr(ty) "as" ident(id) :=
  eassert (id : ty) by eassumption.

Lemma l0 : forall P1 P2, P1 \/ (P1 = P2) -> P2 -> P1.
Proof.
  intros.
  summon (_ \/ _) as HH.
  destruct HH.
  assumption.
  summon (_ = _) as HH.
  rewrite HH.
  assumption.
Qed.
```

You can make `summon`-sans-`as` name the found assumption `it`, while booting anything else under that name out.

```
Tactic Notation "summon" uconstr(ty) "as" ident(id) :=
  eassert (id : ty) by eassumption.

Tactic Notation "summon" uconstr(ty) :=
  let new_it := fresh "it"
   in (try (rename it into new_it); summon ty as it).

Lemma l0 : forall P1 P2, P1 \/ (P1 = P2) -> P2 -> P1.
Proof.
  intros.
  (* This example is actually a bad demonstration of the name-forcing behavior
     because destruct-ion, well, destroys.
     Save the summoned proof under the name it, but destroy it from another,
     then observe the way the second summon shoves the original it into it0. *)
  summon (_ \/ _) as prf.
  pose (it := prf).
  destruct prf.
  assumption.
  summon (_ = _).
  rewrite it.
  assumption.
Qed.
```

Idiomatically, that would really just be

```
Lemma l0 : forall P1 P2, P1 \/ (P1 = P2) -> P2 -> P1.
Proof.
  intros.
  summon (_ \/ _).
  destruct it.
  assumption.
  summon (_ = _).
  rewrite it.
  assumption.
Qed.
```

I believe that you could go and create a bunch of specialized `Tactic Notation`s to replace the `ident` arguments in `destruct`, `rewrite`, etc. with these holey-type `uconstrs`, if you really wanted to. Indeed, `summon _ as _` is almost your modified `rename _ into _`.

Another caveat: `assert` is opaque; the definitions generated by `summon` look like new assumptions that don't reveal that they are equal to one of the old ones. Something like `refine (let it := _ in _)` or `pose` should be used to rectify this, but my L<sub>tac</sub>-fu is not strong enough to do this. See also: this issue advocating for a literal [`transparent assert`](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/3551).

(The new answer solves this caveat.)

Comment: Great! Thank you. I agree that the `=>` syntax adds nothing. I will adapt your first `summon` to avoid duplicating the hypothesis (`match goal with H : _ |- _ => pose (id := H : ty); clear id; rename H into id end.`), and the second one into `Tactic Notation "take" uconstr(ty) "and" tactic(tac) := let new_it := fresh "it" in try (rename it into new_it); summon ty as it; tac; try (rename new_it into it).`, so that I can write, for instance, `take (_ \/ _) and destruct it` which is exactly what I want.